# how to pull data from two tables SQL based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have two tables... cloads and jpurch  I need to pull transactionamount and transaction date column from both tables using one query.  The transactions I need to pull must be between a date range of 1-1-2016 and 3-1-2016.  Obviously the query I posted below wont work since it doesn't even address the jpurch in the where statement. The transaction dates do not need to match.  I need all data for those columns.

```
select c.transactiondate, c.transactionamount, d.transactiondate, d.transactionamount
from cloads c, jpurch d
where c.transactiondate between '2016-05-01' and '2016-06-06'
```

Comment: You need top have a relation between these tables with primary and foreign key concept.
later you can use SQL JOIN in your query to get desired results
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: What is the relation between the two tables?

Answer (score 2):

@sanky send a good article on joins and is a good place to start.  @SujeetSinha also brings up a point about how you will relate one table to the other.

I suspect the answer is you want only records between the tables that match (`INNER JOIN`) and that you want to match on `transactiondate` from one table to the other.  In that case you could write a query like below.  Because both tables have to match on an `inner join` your `where` statement for `cloads` would also filter `jpurch`.

```
select
    c.transactiondate
    ,c.transactionamount
    ,d.transactiondate
    ,d.transactionamount
from
    cloads c
    INNER JOIN jpurch d 
    ON c.transactiondate = d.transactiondate
where
    c.transactiondate between '2016-05-01' and '2016-06-06'
```

Thanks for More Info seems we as a community are still awaiting some help on what you want the data to look like in order to best guide you in your query.  If you can take 3-4 rows from each of your tables show us the beginning data and a mock up of how you want it to look from those rows we will better be able to assist you.

If no relation and into 1 table are up meaning you want to `APPEND` one table to the other? If so use a `UNION or UNION ALL` depending on if you want all of the data returned or only `DISTINCT` values of it. `ALL` means give you everything with `UNION` alone means don't repeat rows that are already in the table on top of the union statement.

```
select
    c.transactiondate
    ,c.transactionamount
from
    cloads c
where
    c.transactiondate between '2016-05-01' and '2016-06-06'

UNION ALL

select
    d.transactiondate
    ,d.transactionamount
from
    jpurch d 
where
    d.transactiondate between '2016-05-01' and '2016-06-06'
```

Comment: How can I pull all data for those date ranges into one table?  The dates do not need to match.

Comment: Edward Perhaps you give us some sample data from each table and how you want it to look? Do you want a full cross join meaning for every date and transaction amount in 1 table you will have every other transaction amount and date combination from the other table?  4 rows becomes 16?   Or are you just trying to make a single table UNION of all transaction dates and amounts?  If the latter should dates and amounts be duplicated or not?